# form_tag with post has a very weird behavior

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord, post, get

I have a very weird behavior by Rails 3.2.

I use a form_tag in my haml page:

```
= form_tag messages_path, :method => :get do
```

this form contains some checkboxes
and this code works fine.

But I don't like get.

If I substitute "get" with "post" something really weird happens:

It appears that the control goes to my "create" method, creates a nil object in my db and then goes back to the original page (that's what I told the "create" method to do anyways).

Then, the checkboxes are pretty messed up...

Note: I save the checkbox contents in the session. Dunno, if it really matters.

Seems like "post" takes you to "create" by default ?? Can I change that ?
"Get" works fine but messes up my url....

any suggestions ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes by default post maps the request to the create method of the controller.

If you want use post request add the below piece of code in config/routes.rb

```
resources :messages do
  collection do
    post 'stuff'
  end
end
```

In your messages controller

```
def stuff
  #your stuff goes here
end
```

Then the form builder will be

```
form_tag stuff_messages_path, :method => :post
```